# How to preserve NA values when using which.min() with apply()?

Tags: r, na

Say I have a data frame where some entire columns are `NA`, like so:

```
set.seed(0)
data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10, 10, 1),
                   B = rnorm(10, 12, 2),
                   C = rep(NA, 10))
```

If I apply `min()` across the columns, I get the output I would hope for:

```
apply(data, 2, min)
#        A        B        C 
# 8.460050 9.524923       NA
```

However, when I apply `which.min()`, my output is a list and the column `C` is gives `integer(0)`:

```
apply(data, 2, which.min)
# $A
# [1] 6
# $B
# [1] 10
# $C
# integer(0)
```

I can make it look the way I want with this rather ugly workaround:

```
which.mins <- unlist(apply(data, 2, which.min))
which.mins[names(data)[!(names(data) %in% names(which.mins))]] <- NA
which.mins
#  A  B  C 
#  6 10 NA
```

Is there a better way to do this, that would mimic the output that I get when using `apply()` with `min()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, `which.min` returns `0` if x has no non-NAs. You can still use `apply` and `which.min` like this:

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) {if (all(is.na(x))) {NA}  else {which.min(x)} })
```

Comment: beat me by 6 seconds =) I was going to suggest
which.mins <- apply(data,2,function(x) if(length(which.min(x))==0) {NA} else {which.min(x)})

Comment: Perfect!  Also, very nice to know about the all() function--that could come in very handy.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that calling `apply` on a data.frame causes the data.frame to be coerced to a matrix before the function is applied.  You should use `sapply` (or `vapply`) instead, else you may get strange errors because all the columns of your data.frame get coerced to a common type (often character).

Just test if the length of the result of `which.min` is zero and return `NA` in that case.

```
> # if() evaluates to FALSE if length(wm) is 0 because as.logical(0) is FALSE
> sapply(data, function(x) if(length(wm <- which.min(x))) wm else NA)
 A  B  C 
 6 10 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about apply() coercing data.frame to matrix--that's something to look out four.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is not giving an NA value because it's detecting NAs in your vector and returning them as the min value, it's giving an NA because there are no numbers in column C of your data frame so it can't return a number to position 3 of the numeric vector `min` returns. `which.min()` returns a list of lists of positions of the minimum value:

```
str(apply(data, 2, which.min)[1])
List of 1
 $ A: int 6
```

And since there is no minimum value in column C it returns a list of length 0, giving you the `integer(0)` result.

You workaround is fine if that's what you're trying to do. Alternatively you could just wrap the whole thing in a function

```
whichMinNAs <- function(x){
  if(FALSE %in% is.na(x)){
    return(which.min(x))
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

apply(data, 2, whichMinNAs)

 A  B  C 
 6 10 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a work-around:

```
apply(data, 2, FUN=function(x) ifelse(length(test<-which.min(x))>0, test, NA))

> apply(data, 2, FUN=function(x) ifelse(length(test<-which.min(x))>0, test, NA))
 A  B  C 
 6 10 NA
```