# R - data.table assign the name of a column that is the minium of a row as value to new column

Tags: r, data.table

Thanks to both of you for suggesting elegant solutions! Both solutions worked for me, but only the `melt()` and back-join solution worked for a data.table with dates instead of numeric values.

**EDIT**

I implemented the proposed **data.table solution through melting and joining back with the obtained results** from Wimpel as his/her solution also works with dates stored in the date columns instead of the intial toy data that was all integer values.

I prefered the readability of Peace Wang's solution though using **data.table assignments** and IMO it is much clearer syntax than the `melt()` solution, however (at least for me), it does not work with columns of type date.

Benchmarking both solutions for numeric/integer data, saw the `melt()` solution as clear winner.

---

**EDIT 2**
To replicate the NA-values through conversion that I get if I implement the solution proposed by Peace Wang, see below for the corrected version of the input data.table.

I have sth like this:
Image a list of patient records with measurements taken at various dates. The colnames of the date columns would be sth like "2020-12-15" / "2021-01-15" etc.

```
 ID   Date_1       Date_2      Date_3   
  1   1990-01-01   1990-02-01  1990-03-01      
  2   1990-01-01   1990-02-01  1990-03-01       
  3   1990-01-01   1982-02-01  1990-03-01
```

I have determined the mimum value of each row in my data.table `dt` like this:

```
dt <- dt[, Min := do.call(pmin, c(.SD, list(na.rm = TRUE))), .SDcols = -(1)]
```

So far so good. Now I want to add a new col `Min_Date` stating the corresponding col name (aka date in my example) of the found miniumum value per row to finally get sth lik this:

```
  ID   Date_1       Date_2      Date_3        Min        Min_Date
  1    1990-01-01   1990-02-01  1990-03-01   1990-01-01  Date_1
  2    1990-01-01   1990-02-01  1990-03-01   1990-01-01  Date_1
  3    1990-01-01   1982-02-01  1990-03-01   1982-02-01  Date_2
```

I tried variations of:

```
dt <- dt[, Min_Date := do.call(which.pmin, c(.SD, list(na.rm = TRUE))),
                           .SDcols = (2:4)]
```

and then trying to do sth with the col index. Don't really know my way around `.I` yet, but I couldn't make it work when used in sth along these lines:

```
exclusions.dt[exclusions.dt[, .I[which.min(.SD)], ISSUE_ID, .SDcols = (2:6)]$V1]
```

Would appreciate any pointer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For each row return the column name of the largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value)

Comment: dt[,(date_min = colnames(.SD)[apply(.SD,1,which.min)]),.SDcols=!1]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just powered down my computer. I‘ll try it first things tomorrow morning and report back.

Comment: Understanding what the proposed does internally, I wonder why it is giving me repetitive warnings about ```NAs created through conversion``` ...

Comment: I don't get any warnings. What's the code? Maybe you can try to check each 'atom' part from a compound code.

Comment: While obviously ```dt[, colnames(.SD), .SDcols=!1]``` returns the names of the columns and I understand we apply row-wise the function ```which.min()``` that is supposed to return the corresponding column index so we can feed it into the .SD - subset data.table and extract the column name

Comment: However applying your suggested line of code to my specific example that only requires changing out the data.table name to sth else as the structure of the table is equal, I get with ```exclusions.dt[,(EXCL_REASON = colnames(.SD)[apply(.SD, 1, which.min)]), .SDcols = !1]``` the said error....

Comment: I don't fully understand yet the placing of the square brackets and I tried a variation being: ```exclusions.dt[, EXCL_REASON := colnames(.SD[, apply(.SD, 1, which.min)]), .SDcols = !1]``` but the same ````generated NA``` warning. Thank you however for the great starting point!!! I will keep trying to figure out what is causing this on my end

Comment: One more question though: Would this theoretically still work with NAs in the original base data.table, so that some rows contain ```NAs``` in the date columns?

I did also try a version with specified in the same line of code ```colnames(.SD)[apply(.SD, 1, which.min, na.rm = TRUE)])``` but that didn't run saying ```unused argument```

Comment: ```:=```  will create a new column on the data.table. ```=``` will  extract sth as a columns( not change original data.table).

Comment: ```dt[,.(date_min = colnames(.SD)[apply(.SD,1,which.min)]),.SDcols=!1]``` This will be better, ```.( )`` means ```list( )```.

Comment: For the ``NAs`` case,  you can check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362561/how-to-preserve-na-values-when-using-which-min-with-apply/22363081. Or you can try to exclude the NAs with ```i``` in  ```dt[i,j,by]```.

Comment: Great, I'll give it try. But, just to clarify - I actually do want to add a new column named ```date_min``` to the data.table ```dt``` and not just extract the information. I first find the minimum value and store it in the column ```Min``` that is added to the original ```dt``` and then subsequently I want to store the measurement date that corresponds to each ```IDs``` minimum measurement. This is why I used ```:=```. I thought this was the correct way of adding a newly computed column

Comment: I see, then you need to use ```:=```.

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks for the quick feedback!

Comment: My pleasue. Good luck.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but still this is giving me the same error/warning. I am bummed. I'll keep trying anyways! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another `data.table` approach

```
#sample data
library( data.table )
DT <- fread("ID   Date_1   Date_2   Date_3   
  1    100      200      300      
  2    100      500      300      
  3    200      150      400    ")

#melt to long format and get rows with minimum value by ID
DT.min <- melt( DT, id.vars = "ID" )[ , .SD[ which.min(value) ], by = ID]
#    ID variable value
# 1:  1   Date_1   100
# 2:  2   Date_1   100
# 3:  3   Date_2   150

#join back to DT
DT[ DT.min, `:=`( Min = i.value, Min_Date = i.variable ), on = .(ID)][]
#    ID Date_1 Date_2 Date_3 Min Min_Date
# 1:  1    100    200    300 100   Date_1
# 2:  2    100    500    300 100   Date_1
# 3:  3    200    150    400 150   Date_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try. Just for clarification, where is the ```DT.lookup``` coming from?

Comment: Ah, it took a while to fully comprehend and implement this conversion in my function, but basically the ```DT.lookup``` is the computed ```DT.min``` in the prior step that we want as a ```lookup``` for the subsequent join as it contains all the wanted data. - Did I get this right?

It works! Much obliged!

Comment: One follow-up question though. How would this solution behave if within a given row there are more than n>1 date that are equal to the minimum of a given row? Would it then just select the first matched (as seen from LHS to RHS) value's column name as ```Min_Date```?

Comment: Yes. And sorry for the naming mixup :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code can work.

```
dt <- fread("
             ID   Date_1   Date_2   Date_3
  1    100      200      300
  2    100      500      300
  3    200      150      400
")
dt[, `:=`(Min = do.call(pmin, c(.SD, list(na.rm = TRUE))),
          date_min = colnames(.SD)[apply(.SD, 1, which.min)]
         ), 
   .SDcols = -1]
```

If you got the `NAs` warning, maybe you can try to refresh `dt` firstly.

Comment: Thanks again Peace Wang for your proposed solution. However, I do still get ```NAs generated through conversion warnings```. As my data.table is quite long and the continiously printed warning to the console slowed things down tremendously, I wrapped the solution code into ```suppressWarnings({ your code })``` and inspected the output. The first part works as expected, computing the ```Min``` and storing it in the ```Min``` column. However, the ```date_min``` column is filled with ```NAs``` only.

Comment: Do you get the warning after you copy and run my whole code? I suggest you to clean your variable environment with ```rm(list = ls())``` (expecially for **dt**).

Comment: Huh, that's a bummer. Based on the toy data, all runs smoothly as expected.... I'll try again after clearing my environment

Comment: That makes sense. I guess your ```NAs generated through conversion warnings``` warning is due to your multi ```:=``` on ```dt``` or ```exclusions.dt```. The first ```:=``` operation should run everything as expected after clearing your environment.

Comment: I edited the main question so that the data includes now real dates instead of toy integer values. With these values, you should also see ```NAs``` in the ```date_min``` column on your end

Comment: It looks now like this. ```fread("ID  Date_1  Date_2  Date_3  1 1990-01-01 1990-02-01  1990-03-01 2 1990-01-01 1990-02-01 1990-03-01 1990-01-01 1982-02-01 990-03-01") ```